# Has been done. what is the correct way to use it?

Tags: tense

I just want to know that I am using this pattern correctly or not.

I normally say "This amount has been paid by a check".

Is the use of "has been paid" correct here?

Comment: Use the simple past when referring to specific dates in the past. *Carrier **received** the claim on 6.20.2018 and **processed** it on 6.21.2018.  Aetna **has paid** $600 by check*.

Comment: It sounds more natural to this US English speaker to say "**with** a check".  "*By* a check" makes it sound like the check was doing the act of paying.  I would normally say something like "The bill was paid **by** Mr. Ngozi **with** a check."

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I always had a weird feeling about that. What if I say it like this? "Insurance has allowed $100.00 and that has been transferred to patient's deductible." is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use "has been paid" to indicate that "now you have the money".

Comment: OK. The complete comment I type is "Carrier has received the claim on 06.20.2018 and processed on 06.21.2018. Aetna has paid $600.00 by a check." Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: If you have a new question please ask it,  this "complete" comment does not contain a "has been done" structure.

Comment: Sorry! I cannot change the comment. Also, I was at the office. Complete comment is like this, "The claim was received on 06.20.2018 and processed on 06.21.2018. Aetna has allowed $600.00 and that has been paid by a check."
I am not really sure that this comment is correct.